# TypeError: name.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating some auto-complete code to list countries from a JSON array. It works fine, but with an error in console. I don't know when it will be harmful. Please can you help to solve this?

CSS

```
.mainpart {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.first {
    width:150px;
    height:25px;
    float:left
}
.second {
    width:150px;
    height:25px;
    float:left
}
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
}
.li-autoList {
    background-color:#CBCACC;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="mainpart">
    <div class="first">
        <input type="text" id="county" onclick="autoList('#county','country')" />
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <input type="text" id="county2" onclick="autoList('#county2','city')" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function autoSort(id,list){

    if(list=='country'){
      county=(co.response.data);
    }else{
      county=(ci.response.data);    
    }

    li='';

    for(i=0;i<county.length;i++){
      c=$(id).val().toUpperCase().replace(/["'\(\)]/g, "");
      conDec=county[i].description+'('+county[i].cod+')';
      conDec=conDec.toUpperCase().replace(/["'\(\)]/g, "");
      n=(conDec.search(c));

      if(n>=0){
        cname=county[i].description+'('+county[i].cod+')';
        li+='<li class="li-autoList"><input type="checkbox" class="itm"    value="'+county[i].description+'('+county[i].cod+')">'+county[i].description+'</li>';
      }

    }

    $('.li-autoList').remove();
    $(id).after(li);
  }

  function autoList(id,list){

    if(list=='country'){
      county=(co.response.data);
    }else{
      county=(ci.response.data);    
    }

    li='';

    for(i=0;i<county.length;i++){
      c=$(id).val().toUpperCase().replace(/["'\(\)]/g, "");
      conDec=county[i].description+'('+county[i].cod+')';
      conDec=conDec.toUpperCase().replace(/["'\(\)]/g, "");
      n=(conDec.search(c));
      chk='';

      if(conDec==c){
        chk='checked';
      }

      cname=county[i].description+'('+county[i].cod+')';
      li+='<li class="li-autoList liItm"><input type="checkbox" '+chk+' class="itm"   value="'+county[i].description+'('+county[i].cod+')">'+county[i].description+'</li>';
    }

    $('.li-autoList').remove();
    $(id).after(li);

    $('.itm').click(function(){ $(id).val( $(this).val()); 
      $('.li-autoList').remove();
      //  autoList(id,list);
    });

    $('.liItm').click(function(){ 
      //  $(id).val( $(this).val()); 
      var cb = $(this).find(":checkbox")[0];
      $(id).attr('checked',true);
      $(id).val( $(cb).val()); 
      $('.li-autoList').remove();
      //  autoList(id,list);
    }); 

    $(id).bind({
      'keyup': function() {
        $('.itm').removeAttr('checked');    
        autoSort(id,list)
      },
      blur: function() {
        //if checkbox checked
        if(!$('.itm').attr('checked'&&( $(id).val()==''))){
          $(id).val(null);
          autoList(id,list)
        }

      }
    });
  }
  var ci={"response":{"status":"0", "data":[{"cod":"SLST" ,"description":"San Luis Talpa"      , "group":"SV"},{"cod":"SA6" ,"description":"San Salvador" , "group":"SV"}]}}; 
  var co={"response":{"status":"0", "data":[{"cod":"FR-AG" ,"description":"Agay" , "group":"Altro"},{"cod":"FR-AI" ,"description":"Aix En Provence" , "group":"Altro"},{"cod":"AL" ,"description":"Albania" , "group":"Le più cliccate"},{"cod":"DZ" ,"description":"Algeria" , "group":"Altro"},{"cod":"FR-AM" ,"description":"Amiens" , "group":"Altro"},{"cod":"AD" ,"description":"Andorra" , "group":"Altro"},{"cod":"ZW" ,"description":"Zimbabwe" , "group":"Altro"}]}};
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: You don't have any `toLowerCase` in your code at all!

Comment: What's the stack trace? Can you replicate on jsfiddle?

Comment: TypeError: name.toLowerCase is not a function  is the only error i get in console.

Comment: Which line does the error message point to?

Comment: @jjjI have the same error in typescript in my ionic app but there are not any   : (name || "").toLowerCase in my code ... TypeError: (name || "").toLowerCase is not a function
    at normalizeName (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:252865:23)
    at getZone (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:252887:10)
    at Function.tz (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:252978:11)
    at DateTimeService.webpackJsonp.144.DateTimeService.getTimezoneDate (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4556:84)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should be wrong in this line:

```
if (!$('.itm').attr('checked' && ($(id).val()==''))) {
```

It might look like this:

```
if (!$('.itm').attr('checked') && ($(id).val()=='')) {
```